# Kendo DataSource and nested Json

Tags: json, kendo-ui

I'm having trouble finding any documentation that accurately describes what to do in a situation like this.

I have the following schema for my `DataSource`:

```
schema: {
    model: {
        id: "Id",
        fields: {
            BuyerProfile: [
                {
                    Id: { type: "number" },
                    Name: { type: "string" },
                    City: { type: "string" },
                    State: { type: "string" },
                    Description: { type: "string" },
                    BuyerType: [
                        {
                            Id: { type: "number" },
                            Name: { type: "string" }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

My JSON is formatted fine and I don't get any errors. But when I try to print any of the items out in my kendo template I just get `undefined` printed.

For example:

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="profileTemplate">
    <p> #:BuyerProfile.Name# </p>
</script>
```

The above example is literally just printing out `undefined` inside of the `p` tags. No JavaScript errors or anything though.

I might be wrong but I thought I read somewhere that this is how you go about using nested JSON objects with Kendo. However, it's clearly not since it's not working or I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Answer you are looking is probably [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24432464/kendo-data-grid-how-to-set-column-value-from-nested-json-object) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17231153/how-can-i-use-nested-json-to-populate-kendo-ui-grid). Basically you either need to parse your schema or just make you schema flat without any nested properties.